# On WCF Client with webHttpBinding and secure transport, intermittent "Underlying Connection Closed"

Tags: asp.net, wcf

During the baseline tests for our automated load testing, we are seeing intermittent "The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server" exceptions.  We've added retry logic at the application layer and the second try goes through fine.  However, this still happens often enough -- roughly 5% of the time -- under even minimal load that we'd like to address the underlying issue if possible.

This is a WCF client connecting to a Java-based Server.  We are partners in this project with the firm hosting the server, so we can request changes on their end, but we don't know what to ask for.

The sockets that are closing are not long lived compared to the others.

Configuration looks like this:

```
   <client>
  <endpoint address="https://example.com/cgi-bin/blahblahblah/dev/Adapter"
      binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DecisionBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"
      contract="Engine.DecisionPortType" name="DecisionPort" />
  </client>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DecisionBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
        maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"            
    writeEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
        <!--            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" /> -->
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

We've added System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; in our code, but that just skips the check to see if the connection is still open before sending.

We've got verbose tracing on in the service trace, but it isn't giving us any insight.

How can we eliminate these exceptions?

Thanks!